# No Letterhead or official email id for Letter of recommendation

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, united-states, recommendation-letter

I worked with a professor on my final year project who has now left the college to finish his Ph.D. He is currently working as an assistant professor at some other college. As I worked closely with that professor, I thought of asking LOR from him. But, as he left my college, his official email ID is of the other college. I will not be able to ask for a letterhead from my college for the LOR written by the professor from another college. Does a LOR taken from such a professor affect my admission process?

Comment: One thing you should *not* do is try to "fake" it by asking for a LoR not on letterhead. It looks like deception, it quacks like deception, it waddles like deception. Even if it's not, if it's discovered they will treat you like roast duck.

Comment: @puppetsock You have lucidly cleared the consequences of faking. However, my issue is genuine, and I am asking for serious consequences regarding LOR from such a professor on my admission process than what will happen if LORs are faked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine for the professor to use an email address and letterhead from the college where the professor works now.

Comment: Will the admission committee contact the professor to verify the details then?

Comment: Assume that they will and act accordingly.